# Free-to-use parenting style questionnaire

Tags: measurement, personality, psychology, parenting

I'm working on a master's thesis in UX design that I might want to turn into a commercial project later on. The subject matter is use of Nonviolent Communication (NVC) in parenting.

For the research phase, as part of a screener, I want to get a sense of a person's parenting style. I've been looking for questionnaires on evaluating parenting styles and found the [Parental Authority Questionnaire](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16370893).

However, this questionnaire was made to be evaluated by children, not by the parents themselves. Is there an alternate questionnaire for them? Would I be able to use its questions in my screener? What are the regulations regarding using questions from a different questionnaire?

Comment: I also found a shorter version, which I'd actually prefer to use: http://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/sbp/sbp/2011/00000039/00000009/art00005;jsessionid=ryj09h5yv3lg.x-ic-live-01

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of parenting style questionnaires. Without knowing what dimensions of parenting style are of key interest, how long you want the questionnaire to be (e.g., trade-offs between validity, reliability with ease) and such, it's hard to recommend a particular one. You can see several from the parent perspective here: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=parenting+style+questionnaire

As to regulations, you may need to contact the authors or journal about whether the scale is permissible for commercial use. I've only ever used scales for academic use.

Comment: I'd like a scientifically verified questionnaire, the shorter the better, intended for parents, with the dimensions being authoritative, authoritarian, permissive, and neglectful. Could you recommend one, or even several?

Comment: @TinMan - Asking for recommendations is asking for someone's opinion on the best one to use and that is off-topic here.  I believe the answer given here is the best that can be given as far as I can see without going outside the scope of this site, but I could be wrong. As for scientific validity, when I click on the link provided it gives one for parents via researchgate.